# LINQ XML Subquery - Need Assistance

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My current LINQ query and example XML are below. What I'd like to do is select the primary image urls from the  as well as the other attributes such as trim, body, make, model, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

```
<response>
<objects>
    <object>
        <trim>LT</trim>
        <body>4dr Car</body>
        <warranty_miles />
        <color>WHITE</color>
        <selling_price>0.00</selling_price>
        <vin>1g1jc5sh3c4198042</vin>
        <has_service_contract >False</has_service_contract>
        <year>2012</year>
        <alt_id></alt_id>
        <stock_num>1205362</stock_num>
        <has_warranty>False</has_warranty>
        <warranty_month />
        <make>CHEVROLET</make>
        <date_manufactured />
        <interior_color>Dark Pewter/Dark Titanium</interior_color>
        <date_updated>2012-10-17</date_updated>
        <date_dealer_created>2012-06-06</date_dealer_created>
        <certification_warranty />
        <status/>
        <vevo></vevo>
        <image_urls>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/1764e186eabe4ae892f6230107b862cf.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/3eeb7050770849e8937191d09453d936.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/7f6c1f172f7b4944ac2d165c0dfbcb09.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/82d242ba07bb4bb9a7c8514ea1aadae7.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/93e3cac89d0f4872b86acd9c2d94695a.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/edec4ffe9b2349ffabea9dcb25a78d1e.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/f2c1dbb15fec4cf6a62b7842db22763a.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
            <object>
                <url>http://content.homenetiol.com/1593/69025/640x480/fa7341e250654533a9de2a756d4274eb.jpg</url>
                <resource_uri></resource_uri>
            </object>
          </image_urls>
       </object>
   </objects>
 </response>
```

Here is what I have so far

```
        var users = from m in main2.Elements("object")
                    select new Inventory 
                    {
                        Make = (string)m.Element("make"),
                        Year = (string)m.Element("year"),
                        Model = (string)m.Element("model"),
                    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to project the collection of objects under the `image_urls` node into a list.

This will project it into a list of strings.

```
select new Inventory
{
    Make = (string)m.Element("make"),
    Year = (string)m.Element("year"),
    Model = (string)m.Element("model"),
    Urls = m.Element("image_urls").Elements().Select(e => (string)e.Element("url"))
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Works! Much appreciated for your time and effort!